# Relaunch a list of record in a program

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am trying to create a Java Program that has the ability to retry itself when an exception occur in the program **(which work fine)**. Now the problem I have now is in the **for loop**. In this code, when something went wrong  in the for loop, the program itself will jump out of that loop and go to the catch method. After that **if the retry is less than MAX_RETRIES**, then the program will ***relaunch from the beginning***. This is what I am struggling with. What I want is let say if there is an exception occur in the for loop when printing let say 5, I want the program to **retry where the exception in the for loop occur** not relaunch from the beginning. Are there ways to do it? I am struggling with this for a while and cannot seems to find a way to do it. Help and code for reference will be appreciated. This is the best way I can think of to simplify my code. In my real application, the for loop I have right now is to Iterate though a list of record from the database.

main.java

```
public class main {
    private static int retryCounter = 1;
    private static int MAX_RETRIES = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int retry = 1;


        try {
            while (retry <= MAX_RETRIES) {

                //method1
                //stuff code
                //more code
                //method2


                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

                    System.out.println("i");
                }


            }

            System.out.println("-----Finish Process-----");


            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printlnStackTrace();

            retry++;

            if (retry == MAX_RETRIES) {
                System.out.println("Program retried" + retry);
                System.out.println("Program Terminated");

            }

        }





    }
```

Comment: Declate "i" outside the "for" and change this one to a "while" loop.

Comment: agree with @pasabaporaqui OR add one more try catch for "for" loop and set flag to Loop again

Comment: Hi thank for your respond. I am wondering if you can provide some code or edit my code? thanks

Comment: What u expected when you've error at for loop ?

Comment: Let say I have 10 items in the loop. When item 4 have exception occur, it will retry that item 4 three times not retry from beginning item 1.  If the exception was fixed at item 4, then it will continue to check item 5, item 6, item7 and so on.

Comment: When an exception occurs, the normal flow of the program is interrupted. When an exception occurs at a line, all the code in the `try` block after that is skipped and the `catch` block is executed. So declaring `i` outside the `for` loop won't do any good (I THink).

Comment: do you have any logic to fix when exception occur ?

Comment: yeah, i placed it in the catch. it is just `if(retry ==MAX_RETRIES) { //fix this code here)}`

Comment: I've updated my answer. accept my answer if u wonder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it solve your problem

```
public class main {
    private static int retryCounter = 1;
    private static int MAX_RETRIES = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int retry = 1;

        while (retry <= MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {

                //method1
                //stuff code
                //more code
                //method2


                int i=0;
                while (i < 11) {

                    try {

                         System.out.println(i);
                          i++;

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                        i++;

                        if (i == MAX_RETRIES) {
                            System.out.println("Program retried" + retry);
                            System.out.println("Program Terminated");

                        }

                    }
                }


                retry++;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                retry++;

                if (retry == MAX_RETRIES) {
                    System.out.println("Program retried" + retry);
                    System.out.println("Program Terminated");

                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("-----Finish Process-----");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that might help. I can't show any example code, but it might be possible to set up a flag/signal<sup>1</sup> after you complete each step in executing the program. Then, when the program retries, it can automatically skip to that point in code where it last stopped.

<sub>1: I don't know what it's called in java</sub>